# C# Winform Application With MySql as Database Deployement

Tags: c#, mysql, deployment

I am working on C# Winform application (Visual Studio 2010) with MySql as back-end. Meanwhile I am looking for a suitable solution to a problem about How will I deploy this application along with MySql server. As this will be multiuser application, embedded database is not an option. It need to be a server based.

There should be one server, for which this combine deployment is required, for client, ofcourse only application installation is required.

So what are the options do I have for deployment? If I am offering this application available for download from a website, should I break it into 2 separate downloads? One is MySql itself (I am using XAMPP bundle for MySql because it is easy and portable), Second is the application alongwith it's all dependencies. If this approach is followed, then I've to setup whole database required by application from within the application (which I think is not so difficult). But then end user have to download the whole package of MySql, is there anyway I can reduce the size of whole XAMPP package as I am only using MySql database, As I don't use anything else in XAMPP (PHP/Apache/Mercury Mail etc) can I remove them so that size of bundle will be small enough for end user to download?

I've searching long for the solution, and many forums (Including SO) has many questions about it, but there are no helpful solutions. I am looking for better solution from experts of this forum.

Thanks and best regards

Ahmed

Comment: What's wrong with just using one of the [installers for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Actually I am looking for available options. I've checked Installers for MySql, it's 212 mb size!!! If I bundle it with my application then a rough estimate of finish apps will be over 280mb...any lightweight options?